# How do transfers of ownership affect artifact concordance?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

My adventuring party recently completed Gardmore Abbey and has possession of of the Deck of Many Things. The starting concordance score included a bonus for having reassembled the Deck, which was awarded to the original keeper of the deck.

However, they have now decided to change owners (i.e. hand it from one player to the other). How does this affect its concordance? Do I reset the score from scratch? If so, do I include the bonus for reassembling the deck? Or do I go from the concordance score the original owner had?

Comment: If the new owner was aiding the party when the deck was reassembled you could still give him that bonus. It's possible the deck may have been witness to some of the concordance-affecting choices of the new owner, so you can tweak the concordance a little if you'd like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from the description of concordance on DMG page 164:

> ### Concordance
>
> An artifact’s concordance score measures the artifact’s attitude toward its wielder. The scale ranges from 0 (angered) to 20 (pleased).
>
> When a character takes possession of an artifact, it starts with a concordance of 5. (The owner’s race, class, or other characteristics might adjust this starting concordance.) Various actions and events increase or decrease this score as long as the character possesses the artifact. When the artifact is pleased with its wielder’s actions, its concordance goes up. When the wielder acts contrary to the artifact’s desires, its concordance decreases.

Since concordance is the artifact's attitude *toward its wielder*, an artifact should be considered as having a different concordance score for each individual wielder.

Suppose Alphonse acquires a *Deck of Many Things*, and raises its concordance with him to 12 - the *Deck of Many Things* is pleased with him! If Alphonse then hands the *Deck of Many Things* to Bertha, Bertha's now its wielder. The *Deck of Many Things* has no opinion of her yet, so its concordance with her is 5. When Bertha hands the *Deck of Many Things* back to Alphonse in the future, its concordance with him is still 12 like it used to be.

## A special case: shared artifacts

Some artifacts are designed to be shared between all party members. In this case, the DM should consider treating the artifact's "wielder" as the entire party for most intents.

## An example: Finding new owners

Many artifacts explicitly try to move on to new owners, such as the Orb of Light, whose *Moving On* description says this:

> ### Moving On
>
> *"We have made the world a better place."* One morning, the Orb is gone, replaced by a luminescent (but mundane) pearl worth 5,000 gp. The former owner gains a permanent +1 bonus to AC against attacks by undead creatures.If the owner failed the Orb, the next time the character lifts it, the artifact crumbles into coal, leaving permanent marks on the character's hand. The former owner takes a permanent -1 penalty to AC against attacks by undead creatures. The Orb reappears elsewhere in the world, ready to be claimed by another aspirant.

Note that last sentence: the Orb decides it should seek out a new owner eventually. *Every* new artifact you find, including the Orb of Light, starts at a concordance around 5, despite the fact that just yesterday, it might have been possessed by someone who had a concordance of 50+ with it. If its concordance was absolute between all wielders, an artifact's starting score should vary heavily depending on who its previous wielder was - but it doesn't vary. It starts at around 5 regardless of who it was previously owned by.

New owner, new concordance.